# Issues sending HTTP messages using Telnet?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am going through exercises in the book "Sinatra Up & Running" and am trying to send HTTP messages to Sinatra using Telnet.

This is what I am trying to do

```
[~]$ telnet 0.0.0.0 4567
```

However, I get the error:

```
Trying 0.0.0.0...
telnet: connect to address 0.0.0.0: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

Sinatra is listening on localhost:4567 instead of 0.0.0.0:4567 and I think that is indicative of the problem.

I found some documentation at http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html that talks about being able to specifically configure the development environment to listen on 0.0.0.0. I passed in:

```
ruby server.rb -o set :bind, '0.0.0.0'
```

And was able to adjust where Sinatra was listening to 0.0.0.0:4567 but `telnet 0.0.0.0 4567` still gives the same error messages.

Comment: The command `ruby server.rb -o set :bind, '0.0.0.0'` is incorrect, and will likely result in an error. Did you mean you used `ruby server.rb -o 0.0.0.0` or did you add `set :bind, '0.0.0.0'` to your app?

Comment: I ran `$ ruby server.rb -o set :bind, '0.0.0.0'`

Comment: Unless you have set up a network interface named `set`, that command will most likely result in an error.

Answer (score 1):

When you tell the server to listen on `0.0.0.0`, that isn't actually a specific address, you're really telling it to bind to all available network interfaces. To connect to it, use either `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`, which are special addresses that always mean "this host":

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 4567
```

Comment: I tried adjusting the host `$ ruby server.rb -o 0.0.0.0` but both of those connection methods gave me the same error messages `telnet: connect to address fe80::1: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host` I also turned off my firewall in system preferences.

Answer (score 0):

If you bind Sinatra to 0.0.0.0:4567 and it is listening they you will be able to externally hit your machine via the machine's ip.

E.g. machine-01 (192.168.122.100) is running Sinatra, which is bound to 0.0.0.0:4567 then from machine-02 (192.168.122.200) you'll be able to telent 192.168.122.100:4567 (provided there are no firewalls).

As the other post suggested, if you're trying to do it all on machine-01, then you want to bind Sinatra to localhost:4567 (127.0.0.1:4567), then you will be able to telenet localhost:4567

Comment: I tried changing my host like this `$ ruby server.rb -o 127.0.0.1:4567` Then I exited the server and ran `$ telenet localhost:4567` and it gave the error message `bash: telenet: command not found`

Comment: Check and see if your server is running. If you do a sudo netstat -tulpn | grep ":4567" you should see something like 0.0.0.0:4567 LISTEN or 127.0.0.1:4567 LISTEN. If you don't your service is not running at all or not on port 4567.